# How to sum profits of all products using AVG prices in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

In my SQLite I have the following tables:

```
Products:
Pro_id.    Pro_name
1.        Item1
2.        Item2
3.        Item3
4.        Item4

Purchases:
Pro_id.  Pur_Qty   Pur_Price
1.        10.        10
1.        10.        11
2.        20.        10
2.        10.        12
..        ..         ..

Sales:
Pro_id.    Sa_Qty.     Sa_price
1.          10.          15
1.          10.          20
2.          20.          15
2.          10.          25
```

Now i want:

```
1- to show product ID and product name from products.
2- i want to sum avg prices from both tables sales & purchases and show it.
3- i want to sum profits for all products every product must have it's profits ..
```

How to do that?

I tried this :

```
select
 pro_name,
 sum(sa_qty)* (sum(sa_qty*sa_price)/sum(sa_qty)) -
     sum(sa_qty)*(sum(pur_qty*pur_price)/sum(pur_qty)) as Profits

from products 
left join purchases on purchases.pro_id= products.pro_id 
left join sales on sales.pro_id = products.pro_id 

group by pro_name 
having sales.pro_id
```

Answer (score 1):

As a variant:

```
select
   products.pro_id,
   products.pro_name,
   (select avg(pur_price) from purchases where purchases.pro_id=products.pro_id) +
      (select avg(sa_price) from sales where sales.pro_id=products.pro_id)
      as sum_of_average,
   (select sum(sa_price*sa_qty) from sales where sales.pro_id=products.pro_id) -
      (select sum(pur_price*pur_qty) from purchases where purchases.pro_id=products.pro_id)
      as profits
from products
```

Comment: That is not what I want but your answer made me to understand how to use queries in SQLite  I will post my final solution thanks

Comment: And this saved me a lot now i solved 3 problems in my in my project 

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   products.p_id,
   products.p_name,
   (select avg(sa_price) *
   sum(sa_quantity) from sales where sales.pro_id=products.p_id)
   -
      (select avg(pur_price) from purchases where purchases.pro_id=products.p_id)
      *
      (select sum(sa_quantity) from sales where sales.pro_id=products.p_id) as Profits
      
from products group by products.p_name
```

Comment: You do not need `group by` here. Grouping is done already in subselects.

Comment: Ah ok thanks i just see that when using group by name it groups them alphabeticaly

Comment: No. Sorting has nothing to do with `group by`, If you want sorting, use `order by`.

Comment: Ah ok thanks 